# how to load static page on blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator

I currently have an application that uses a browserfield to access an internet page but I was wondering if it is possible to somehow embed the HTML page with the project so that the browserfield displays that page instead of having to retrieve it from the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this with the 'displayContent' method:
`BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);
BrowserField test = new BrowserField(config);
test.displayContent("Your HTML","");`

Comment: but the method displayContent() was not working for me. i use method requestContent() and its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,
 BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_CARET);
 BrowserField test = new BrowserField(config);
 test.requestContent("Your HTML");
```

this is working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your page in this way

```
BrowserSession session = Browser.getDefaultSession();
session.displayPage("cod://Name of your application code file/test.html");
```

test.html must be the your html page which is stored in your resources.